# Setting XPath violation suppressions in PMD

Tags: xpath, pmd

I'm setting up custom rules in PMD but I am having trouble getting the XPath suppressions to work and without using deprecated features. I am using PMD 6.32.

My rule is to modify the rule `ShortVariable` in the `Java/Codestyle` ruleset:

```
<rule ref="category/java/codestyle.xml/ShortVariable">
        <properties>
            <!-- ignore ID -->
            <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//VariableDeclaratorId[@Image='id']"/>
        </properties>
    </rule>
```

There are two problems I am coming up against:

1. When I run the checks, I get the following in the logs:
   `java.lang.RuntimeException: Use of deprecated attribute 'VariableDeclaratorId/@Image' in a findChildNodesWithXPath navigation, please use @Name instead`. However, when I change any instance of `@Image` to `@Name`, the checks fail.
2. This particular rule isn't functioning as I hoped. I wanted to keep the original rule, but suppress it if the field name is `id`. Instead, it is suppressing the rule for all the variables in the class, if there is a field called `id`. What should the rule be?

**EDIT**
Solved the problem with the `id` rule not being applied correctly by using the following:
`<property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="./.[@Name='id']"/>`

However, after changing instance of `@Image` to `@Name`, some of the other suppresions aren't being applied at all:

`<property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="./MethodDeclarator[@Name='hashCode' or @Name='equals']"/>` shoudl suppress the rule on methods name `hashCode` or `equals`, but isn't

`<property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[@Interface='true' and (ends-with(@Name, 'Repository'))]"/>` should suppress the rule on methods in a class where the name ends with `Repository`, but isn't

`<property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//MethodDeclarator[@Name='main']"/>` should suppress the rule on methods in the main method, but is suppressing the rule on the other methods and the application class

Answer (score 4):

As for your questions:

1. The replacement is correct, there is no difference between one or the other apart from the deprecation, actually [the code reads](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/5650b720b37a6a8e73786b5e1694f66bef390a36/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/ast/ASTVariableDeclaratorId.java#L102-L116):

```java
    /**
     * @deprecated Use {@link #getName()}
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    @DeprecatedAttribute(replaceWith = "@Name")
    @Deprecated
    public String getImage() {
        return getName();
    }

    /** Returns the name of the variable. */
    public String getName() {
        return super.getImage();
    }
```

2. As per [the documentation on XPath suppression](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.32.0/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html#the-property-violationsuppressxpath):

> Note the use of `.` to refer to the context node. Using `//` at the start of the expression should be avoided, as it would test all nodes in the file, and suppress more violations than expected.

So you should just use:

```xml
<property name="violationSuppressXPath" value=".[@Name='id']"/>
```

Comment: Using `<property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="./[@Name='id']"/>` gives me a runtime exception: `org.jaxen.saxpath.XPathSyntaxException: ./[@Name='id']: 2: Expected one of '.', '..', '@', '*', <QName>`

Comment: I've solved that issue with `"./.[@Name='id']"` but I'm now having an issue where other rules have failed, after converting them to use `@Name`. I'll update my initial question with the new problems